# Unable to use a hermetic python in a Bazel Workspace as an external dependency

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I've been working on a small project trying to teach myself how to use Bazel. The goal is to download a *http_archive* that contains a python interpreter. once the python interpreter has been added to the environment I want to run the command `python.exe --version and write the output of that into a file

**The issue I have the most difficulty with at the moment are the following:**

1. I am not confident that I am correctly injecting the hermetic python BUILD file into the hermetic python package (I keep getting the message *"BUILD file not found in any of the following directories. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package")*.
2. I'm pretty sure that when I pass in *python_compiler = ["@hermetic_python"]* in the BUILD file I'm just getting a string and not a reference to the files in the package

Here is an overview of my project and the code files. Any help would be appreciated! :D

**Project structure:**

```
|-- WORKSPACE
|-- BUILD
|-- custom_rules.bzl
|-- main.py
|-- custom-rules/
   |-- BUILD.custom_python
   |-- custom_python_rules.bzl
```

**WORKSPACE**

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "hermetic_python",
    urls = ["https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.10/python-3.9.10-embed-amd64.zip"],
    sha256 = "67161cab713a52f6658b76274f8dbe0cd2f256aab1e84f94cd557d4a906fa5d2",
    build_file = "@//:custom-rules/BUILD.custom_python"
  )
```

**BUILD File:**

```
load("//:custom_rules.bzl","build_with_custom_python")

build_with_custom_python(
    name = "write-to-file",
    python_compiler = ["@hermetic_python"]
    )
```

**custom_rules.bzl**

```
def _build_with_custom_python_impl(ctx):
    out_file = ctx.actions.declare_file("file_with_python_version.txt")
    ctx.actions.run(
        outputs = [out_file]
        executable = ctx.attr.python_compiler,
        arguments = [--version],
    )

 return DefaultInfo(files=[out_file])

build_with_custom_python = rule(
    implementation = _build_with_custom_python_impl,
    attrs = {
        "python_compiler": attr.label_list(allow_files=True)
    }
)
```

---

**BUILD.custom_python**

```
load("//:custom_python_rules.bzl","run_me")

run_me(
    name="my_py_run",
    python_files = glob(["**"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

**custom_python_rules.bzl**

```
def _run_me_impl(ctx):
    pass

run_me = rule (
    implementation = _run_me_impl,
    attrs = {
        "python_files" : attr.label_list(allow_files=True),
    }
)
```

Comment: Dropbox open sourced their python bazel build. [https://github.com/dropbox/dbx_build_tools/blob/master/thirdparty/cpython/BUILD.python39](https://github.com/dropbox/dbx_build_tools/blob/master/thirdparty/cpython/BUILD.python39). We modified it to create our internal python bazel build. You can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent some more time on this I've managed to mostly do what I intended to do. Here is an overview of what I've learned that *fixes* the problems in the original question

### 1 - Mark the custom build file / custom rule folder as a package

Just by adding an empty BUILD file into the custom-rules folder I had market it as a bazel package. That allowed me to reference the files

```
|-- WORKSPACE
|-- BUILD
|-- custom_rules.bzl
|-- main.py
|-- custom-rules/
   |-- BUILD # NEW
   |-- BUILD.custom_python
   |-- custom_python_rules.bzl
```

### 2 - The workspace file references a BUILD file. That build file needs to reference a custom rules file

The workspace should just reference the build file directly // means **workspace root** and then its just the path to the BUILD file

```
http_archive(
    # build_file = "@//:custom-rules/BUILD.custom_python" // WRONG
    build_file = "//custom-rules/BUILD.custom_python" // RIGHT
  )
```

### 3 - BUILD file can not reference the custom rules (bzl file)

This is the one that took the longest time for me to figure out! The BUILD file that is loaded into the package (hermetic_python from the workspace file) **NEEDS TO** reference the current workspace in order to

```
# BUILD.custom_python    
load("@root_workspace//custom-rules:custom-python-rules.bzl","execute_python_file")
```

Notice that this starts with @root_workspace which tells the BUILD file to look in that workspace. the WORKSPACE file in the project now contains this line

```
# WORKSPACE
workspace(name = "root_workspace")
```

### 4 - Passing in a build step as the dependancy

```
build_with_custom_python(
    name = "write-to-file",
    # python_compiler = ["@hermetic_python"] WRONG 
    python_compiler = ["@hermetic_python:my_py_run"] RIGHT
    )
```

The key here is that I need to reference a build action which then makes the files in that build action available through the dependency. In this case @hermetic_python is the package and :my_py_run is the build action.

I still need to figure out how to properly use the files in the dependency but that's outside of the scope of this question